# Find in Files command in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssms

Is there way to use the "Find in Files" command for searching all of the stored procedures and views for a particular database in SQL Server 2005 Management Studio?

**Edit**

I want to search all of the stored procedures in database X for string Y.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.

You can however use a query, for exemple:

```
SELECT ROUTINE_SCHEMA, ROUTINE_NAME, ROUTINE_DEFINITION
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE'
AND ROUTINE_DEFINITION LIKE '%searchstring%'
```

This will however not work for CLR or encrypted stored procedures.

Comment: I was looking for this, too, thanks! Would it be churlish of me to suggest SQL Server Management Studio should have a command which does this?